# Projection Matrix for Triangulation of 3D points

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, triangulation

I am confused about what Projection Matrix means. If I have one monocular camera, and I want to triangulate 3D points from image (2D) points of two consecutive frames I_k and I_{k-1}, and I use cv.triangulatePoints which need 2 projection matrix and 2 arrays of 2d points.

So what confuses me is this: As far as I understand, projetion matrix convert 3D points to 2D points, and its format is: K*[R | t], where K is intrinsic parameters. Lets suppose we have Frame k-1, Frame k, and Frame k+1. Let's have a look at triangulatePoints method and its declaration:

```
triangulated4d = cv.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, kp1, kp2);
```

kp1 - KeyPoints from Frame k

kp2 - KeyPoints from Frame k+1

P1,P2 = ?

What are P1 and P2? I mean, do we calculate P1 and P2 every time between 2 frames? Like intrinsic parameters always stay the same, and extrinsic parameters changing because of rotation and translation between two frames.

So my question is: Are P1 and P2:

1. Always fixed: Only calculated one time, with K,R and t from Camera Calibration
2. Not fixed: Always calculated with new R and t (R and t are transformations between Frame k and k+1) and K is fixed

If 2 is answer, what would be P1 and what P2? P1 between (k-1) and k Frame, and P2 between (k) and (k+1) Frame?

I am just begginer at Computer Vision and this confuses me.

Comment: Not that I'm an expert in OpenCV but: `cv.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, kp1, kp2);` -> `cv` is a variable? ...has a class type? ...of OpenCV? OpenCV has a doc. Just search for doc. of this class, and then for the doc. of this `triangulatePoints()`. I more often already looked into the online doc. of OpenCV. IMHO, it's not that bad and seems to be quite complete and encompassing.

Comment: no, cv is another name for cv2 :D When i put same P matrix, I get same 3D points all the time

Comment: OK. I needed a while to understand your comment. So, in this case, your snippet is Python code. (I read it as C++. In C++, a scope operator is `::` while a dot is the select operator exclusively (except it's a decimal point). Hence, I suspected `cv` to be a variable. I know that a dot has both meanings in Python.) Additonally, you didn't mention any language except in the tags. TL;DR: Please, prevent tag spamming.

Comment: So what I am asking is that I don't understand what projection matrix means. Is it connected to camera, and once I calculate it, I am done, or I need to recalculate it for every new frame? If I calculate it from extrinsic and intrinsic paramters only once, and should I I call `triangulatePoints(P,P,kp1,kp2)` like this or this : `triangulatePoints(P1,P2,kp1,kp2)` where I calculate P1 and P2 for every frame (P1 between frames k-1 and k, and P2 between frames k and k+1)

Comment: from the docs: "The function reconstructs 3-dimensional points (in homogeneous coordinates) by using their observations with a stereo camera. Projections matrices can be obtained from stereoRectify()." So 1. you can look what is delivered by stereoRectify function and 2. probably it's the intrinsics*extrinsics because you need the transformation between two cameras for triangulation and 3. if you have a solid stereo setup or a single camera with constant movement, the P1 and P2 will always be constant.

Comment: Thanks @MIcka. One more question, PLEASE. Suppose I am using one monocular camera with known K (intrinsic). Suppose Frame0  coincide with World. For Frame0 projection matrix would be P0 = K*[ I|0], and for Frame1 P1=K*[ R|t] (R and t is transformation between Frame0 and Frame1]. Now just to remind that I am continiously building matrix C by concatenating all transformations between frames (T)  (C=C*T). Now is point where I don't understand. This will be in new comment, sorry

Comment: Lets obtain Frame_(k-1) and Frame_k. For Frame_(k-1), would projection matrix P_(k-1) be: P_(k-1) = K*[ I|0 ] or  P_(k-1) = K*[ R1|t1 ] (where R1 and t1 are taken from absolute transformation C - which I am computing every time). Same for Frame_k. Would it be: P_k = K*[ R|t ] (R and t is transformation between Frame_(k-1) and Frame_k) or P_k = K*[ R2|t2] (where R2 and t2 are taken from absolute transformation C). To remind: R2 and t2 are one multiplication ahead than R1 and t1. I am using all these P matrices to send them to triangulatePoints() function to obtain 3D points. This confuses me :(

Comment: I think you can use either the global or the local transformation. The difference will be that the triangulated points will be either in global or in local 3D space. In the end the only difference should be the origin and the axes of your 3D space (and maybe some numerical stability aspects).